# What does "final word" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Which option should I choose here?
http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/final%20word

> For investors, a sigh of relief over France is understandable. But the election may not yet be the **final word**. ([Source](http://www.marketwatch.com/story/investors-are-breathing-a-sigh-of-relief-over-france-for-now-2017-05-07))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *final word*, also referred to as the *last word* means [the final point (in an argument) or the final decision (in some matter)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/final+word).

With regards to your quote, it establishes that investors were worried about the effect the French election would have on their investments. By saying that the (results of the) election is not the final word, it is saying that these investors can't relax (with regards to their investments) just yet.